# Using regex to check if a string contains only one digit

Tags: java, regex, string, digit

I'm writing an algorithm and I need to check if a string contains **only one** digit (no more than one). Currently I have:

```
if(current_Operation.matches("\\d")){
...
}
```

Is there a better way to go about doing this? Thanks.

Comment: what is wrong with this way?

Comment: The pattern: `^\D*\d\D*$`.

Comment: It seems that I am not getting the correct result with this way. Let me double check

Comment: if a string contains anywhere? I'd be tempted to just write `if(str.length == 1 && isDigit(str[0])`. `isDigit` from `std.ascii` is good enough for a basic check.

Comment: Note that the "d" tag is used for the D programming language, please refrain from using it just because you happen to have a "d" in your example

Comment: More generally, read a tag's excerpt if you're unsure of its meaning.

Comment: @cym13 thanks for pointing it out, silly me thought there would be a tag for regex "\\d". Edited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
^\\D*\\d\\D*$
# match beginning of the line
# non digits - \D*
# one digit - \d
# non digits - \D*
# end of the line $
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/a0ulwZ/1) (added newlines for clarity).

Comment: @Jan In the same regex how can we check if digits are between 0-6 only

Answer (score 1):

If you fancied not using a regular expression:

```
int numDigits = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < current_Operation.length() && numDigits < 2; ++i) {
  if (Character.isDigit(currentOperation.charAt(i))) {
    ++numDigits;
  }
}
return numDigits == 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular expression

```
/^\d$/
```

This will ensure the entire string contains a single digit. The `^` matches the beginning of the line, and the `$` matches the end of the line.

Comment: he asked for checking if the string contains a digit and is not only a digit. But it should only contain exactly one digit

Comment: @WebFreak001 yes, you are correct. The string itself contains parentheses also, but I am checking if it contains only one digit.