# How would I be able to determine if a string contains only one digit?

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

I would need to find if the user input for password contains only 1 digit and I am having trouble what the if statement would be.

I currently only have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static boolean onlyOneDigit (String password) {
    if ( ........ ) {
        System.out.print("Password requirement not met");
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter a password");
        String password = input.next();
    } while (onlyOneDigit(password)); 

    {
        System.out.print("Password updated");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format that code and make it more complete. It is not readable and not valid Java (yet)

Comment: Also, define what you mean by "one number"

Comment: if a user inputs "newpassword234" it would show an error because it has 3 digits when it should only have 1 digit.

Comment: That's not a number. That's a string, which contains some digits at the end.

Comment: sorry that is what i meant, checking a string to make sure it only has one digit

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/39799056/1839439

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  Single digit in password vs no digit or more than one in password.

```
        for (String pw : new String[]{"with1digit", "withtwo22digits","withNodigits",
                "with2scatt2reddi3gits"}) {
            boolean m = pw.matches("[^\\d]*\\d[^\\d]*");
            System.out.println(m + " : " + pw);
        }
```

Prints the following:

```
true : with1digit
false : withtwo22digits
false : withNodigits
false : with2scatt2reddi3gits
```

Example usage.

```
     if (onlyOneDigit(password)) {
         // it's good
     } else {
         // warn user
     }

     public static boolean onlyOneDigit(String pw) {
         return pw.matches("[^\\d]*\\d[^\\d]*");
     }
```

And her is another way

```
        public static boolean onlyOneDigit(String pw) {
            // get rid of the first digit
            String save =pw.replaceFirst("\\d","");
            // replace the next digit with a # 
            save = save.replaceFirst("\\d", "#");
            // if save contains # it had more than 1 digit
            // or if save equals the original password
            // then there were no digits.
            return !(save.equals(pw) || save.contains("#"));
         }
```

Comment: thanks for your input, but is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Well, that's pretty simple to me.  It was just a demo.  I would probably write a method which takes the password (string) as an argument and returns the match value.  Then  you can just call the method in an if statement.

Comment: would the if/else statements be in main method?

Comment: They could be anywhere you want them to be. It depends on how you organize your code.

Comment: What if the password contained `#` because that is what the user entered? What if the string was initially empty?

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex (Regular Expression) to match an optional non-digit string followed by a single digit and then followed by optional non-digit string of characters.

```
public static boolean onlyOneDigit (String password) {
    return password.matches("\\D*\\d\\D*");
}
```

- `\\D*` matches any non-digit character zero or more times
- `\\d` matches a digit only once
- `\\D*` matches any non-digit character zero or more times